# MySQL - Return last row after using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Here is a log of user activity on my project, who have each "voted" on various items, giving each item either a "1", "2" or "3" rating.

```
rec_id | user_id | item_id  | value
-----------------------------------
1      | 1       | 2        | 3
2      | 1       | 2        | 2
3      | 2       | 1        | 1
4      | 3       | 1        | 1
5      | 3       | 2        | 2
6      | 1       | 2        | 1
7      | 1       | 4        | 2
```

I'm trying to return all the item_id's user_id "1" has voted on, and the last value they gave each item. So, my goal is to return the following rows from the full table above:

```
rec_id | user_id | item_id  | value
-----------------------------------
6      | 1       | 2        | 1
7      | 1       | 4        | 2
```

In the first example, user_id "1" has voted on item_id "2" three times, so I want to ignore the previous instances in which user 1 has voted on it.

Here is my statement so far, but this returns "3" for the rating of item_id 2, when it should be "1":

```
SELECT MAX(rec_id), user_id, item_id, value 
FROM logs
WHERE user_id=1
GROUP BY user_id, item_id
```

What do I need to add to reach my goal?

Comment: Duplicate of this tag's most frequently asked question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you just need a subquery where the rec_id is equal to the max rec_id

## QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    rec_id, user_id, item_id, value 
FROM logs
WHERE user_id = 1
  AND rec_id IN
  (   SELECT 
          MAX(rec_id) 
      FROM logs 
      GROUP BY item_id
  )
GROUP BY user_id, item_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f070f/2)

## OUTPUT:

```
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
|rec_id | user_id | item_id  | value |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| 6     | 1       | 2        | 1     |
| 7     | 1       | 4        | 2     |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the last row usually you would use a combination of `order by` and `LIMIT 1`.

In your case I would use two seperate queries though. But I would first restructure my database to avoid religion and duplicates.**strong text**

Comment: to do this type of query you can't use a limit as there is no guarantee of how many item_id's there will be

Comment: Incorrect. To get the `last row` one has to `limit`. However to get the other itemids, we would use a separate query. It is an apples and pears ask.

Comment: there shouldn't be a limit for this query though... only when you want to get the most recent of any you should.. see my answer for clarification.. the id should just be matched in a subquery. no limit needed